# Mass/weight in 2 places at the same time

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mass, fluid-statics, weight, laws-of-physics

Though it may seem like it is not, this is a genuine question of which I cannot find the answer online. The situation of how the question arose may make it seem otherwise.

I monitor my weight every day as part of a fitness plan. Every morning I get up, go to the bathroom, do what I need to do and weigh myself AFTER. Th fact that I do this annoys my doctor for some reason but the major disagreement we have every time is this...
I always weigh myself AFTER I've used the bathroom and she says this will make no difference to my weight. My argument is that whatever has left my body will have a weight/mass and therefore now it is no longer in my body I must be lighter (I understand we're probably just talking ounces). I'm sure years ago in my school days I recall a law in physics stating something like 'weight cannot be in two places at the same time', or something along those lines.
I guess there's a simple answer but logic tells me that if I was holding a concrete block I would be a lot heavier than if I put it down and logic tells me this is the same application but on a smaller scale.
To quote any such law would be great, if nothing more than to just end the argument.

Comment: If she thinks it makes no difference, why does she care? How can this possibly be the source of a “major disagreement”?

Answer (score 0):

You are right! What you are referring too is the conversion of mass! However, as you said, the difference should be extremely small.

Comment: Thanks. Always felt I was correct just through pure logic.

Answer (score 0):

"" logic tells me that if I was holding a concrete block I would be a lot heavier than if I put it down and logic tells me this is the same application but on a smaller scale. To quote any such law would be great, if nothing more than to just end the argument.""

Well , here is a quote from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_mass

> In physics and chemistry, the law of conservation of mass or principle of mass conservation states that for any system closed to all transfers of matter and energy, the mass of the system must remain constant over time, as the system's mass cannot change, so the quantity can neither be added nor be removed. Therefore, the quantity of mass is conserved over time.

> The law implies that mass can neither be created nor destroyed, although it may be rearranged in space, or the entities associated with it may be changed in form

So this describes your "concrete block" example and also your before and after bathroom rearrangement  of the masses involved.